# Angular 4 value set in response subscribe is empty when accessed in other function

Tags: javascript, angular, subscribe

I have a simple subscribe method in which I assign the response to `messageIds`

```
messageIds;

this.messageService.subjectPassMessageId.subscribe(data => {
    this.messageIds = data 
    console.log(this.messageIds)         // ['3', '4', '8']
})
```

But when I access `messageIds` in other function call, its empty, do I miss something?

```
addTagToMessage() {
    console.log(this.messageIds)         // []     empty
}
```

full method:

```
   ngOnInit() {

  this.messageService.subjectPassMessageId.subscribe(data => {
    this.messageIds = data

    console.log("message ids",this.messageIds)
    })

 }

  addTagToMessage() {
   console.log("The message ids", this.messageIds) [] //empty
  }
```

html:

```
  <button (click)="addTagToMessage()">Tag Message</button>
```

Comment: When and where do you call `addTagToMessage()` exactly? Are you sure that you call it after `this.messageIds` has the new value?

Comment: Are you sure that your method `addTagToMessage` is called after calling the subscription?

Comment: yes its called after it, I can see the ids in subscribe, but when I fire AddTafToMessage() function, the messageIds is empty

Comment: I think you should call addTagToMessage inside ngOnInit() {}

Comment: Can you put the code with the sequence of calls?

Comment: Show us your code where you call `addTagToMessage()`.

Comment: updated with more code

Comment: Are you clicking the button after the subscription ends its execution?

Comment: yes after, I can see it before in subscription, but after that when I click button to see it addTagToMessage() method, its empty

Comment: Could be related to the variable's scope?

Comment: @AlexFF1 how did you declare `messageIds`?

Comment: @SrAxi:   messageIds;

Comment: Could you post a stackblitz or plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

messageIds will mostly be getting the value only after executing the addTagToMessage() method. Hope that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix this this what I did, but not sure why it should be like this, maybe someone could exmplain:

```
 messageIds;
 strippedMessageIds;

 this.messageService.subjectPassMessageId.subscribe(data => {
    this.messageIds = data 

    **this.strippedMessageIds = this.messageIds.map(a => a)**

    console.log(this.strippedMessageIds)         // ['3', '4', '8']
  })
```

And now on this function can access it:

```
 addTagToMessage() {
   console.log(this.strippedMessageIds)          // ['3', '4', '8']
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little example, but I got the expected behaviour, the assignment in `this.data = value` is working fine, so both of the `console.log()` statements output the same values.

```
data;

fakeObservable = new Observable(observer => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next([1, 2, 3]);
  }, 5000);
});

subscription = this.fakeObservable.subscribe(
  value => {
    this.data = value;
    console.log(value);
  }
);

show() {
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

What is the type of data? What is the output of `console.log(data)` inside the subscription?

Comment: inside subscription its an array // ['3', '4', '8']. Its very wierd, I have another subscription where I set the value but other data type and its working as expected

Comment: Try to assign other type of variable inside the subscription to see what happens.